# cURL post not working PHP

Tags: php, post, curl

I'm having trouble using cURL for a specific page.

A live code working: http://svgen.com/jupiter.php

Here is my code:

```
    $url = 'https://uspdigital.usp.br/jupiterweb/autenticar';

    $data = array('codpes' => 'someLogin', 'senusu' => 'somePass', 'Submit' => '1');
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "FileHere");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "FileHere");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_HTTP);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Although I had used the same url and post data, file_get_contents worked:

```
    $options = array('http' => array('method'  => 'POST','content' => http_build_query($data)));
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

    var_dump($result);
```

Someone could help me?
Thanks.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Did you get any return?

Comment: I can't authenticate using cURL

Comment: @MaurícioGiordano your server SSL port is enabled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

make your post data as:

```
$data = array('codpes' => 'someLogin', 'senusu' => 'somePass', 'Submit' => '1');
$postData = "";
foreach( $data as $key => $val ) {
   $postData .=$key."=".$val."&";
}
$postData = rtrim($postData, "&");
```

and change:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

to

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
```

Comment: Why not use http_build_query() instead? Check my answer.

Comment: Thanks for this-- for some reason http_build_query() worked for me on one server, but failed on another.  Your solution helped me create a workaround that works on both servers.

Answer (score 14):

Most probably it is the SSL verification problem.

Add

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
```

Also if you use `CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS` option, it should be **HTTPS** since you are posting to a secure url

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_HTTPS);    // you currently have http
```

Comment: @MaurícioGiordano Sorry put 0 instead of false, my mistake

Comment: This helps if your working curl-request strangely does not work inside your Laravel application

Answer (score 7):

```
$data = array('codpes' => 'someLogin', 'senusu' => 'somePass', 'Submit' => '1');
```

should have been

```
$data = http_build_query(array('codpes' => 'someLogin', 'senusu' => 'somePass', 'Submit' => '1'));
```

It automatically url encodes your query string as well and is safer than manual methods..

Answer (score 2):

Try these:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, '/etc/pki/tls/cert.pem'); // path is valid for RHEL/CentOS
```

This makes sure the resource you're "curling" has a valid SSL certificate. It is not recommended to set "CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER" to false (0).

Answer (score 1):

You're on a secure connection, why are you using :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_HTTP);
```

Use instead :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_HTTPS);
```

Comment: It tried both and not working... Note: file_get_contents use HTTP instead of HTTPS and works...

Comment: Then keep `HTTPS`, that's one error less :-) `curl` and `file_get_contents` do not work the same way.