# Post request using curl not working - PHP

Tags: php, post, curl

I want to get the response from a PHP post as a string. I'm using curl, based in some references I've found here.

This is my function:

```
function curlPost($url, $parameters){

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parameters);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
}
```

It really seems right, but when I run it, it just doesn't happen anything. I've tried hardcoding $url and $parameter, but it also didn't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Any reason you have `2` in `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 2);`? Doesn't really matter, just curious.

Comment: Please log and post your `$response`; `curl_error($ch)` if your response is `FALSE`; `curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);` to get response status code.

Comment: Can you show us what `$parameters` holds? And us `$url` going to SSL?

Comment: I was browsing for the solution for days but I couldn't find it. But I just saw the solution here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151739/curl-post-not-working-php). Is was an SSL verification problem. I added `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);` and `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);` and it worked!

Nikolai, I was using `2` because I saw a few posts with `count($parameters)`, so I thought it was how many parameters I was passing.
Thanks for the help, guys!

Comment: @Som - I was facing a similar issue. Your solution worked for me. :)